# Running a 5v motor off a desktop usb port

Tags: usb

I'm attempting to power a 5v motor using a usb port from my desktop. The issue I'm facing is the port not supplying enough power. Instead of providing stable 5V, it provides a lower amount and does it in pulses.
This has worked previously using a different usb cable but that one broke. 
Is there a way to fix the issue and have the port provide constant 5V?

Thank you for all help provided

Comment: Guess: The previous "cable" used resistors or active electronics to signal power usage according to the USB standard. The standards are publicly available, so you could solder your own... for starters, which type of USB you have would be important.

Comment: USB Type A, I tink it's a 2.0. I literally got it for £1 so it's one of those really cheap ones

Comment: It might be better to ask this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ Most PC USB ports supply up to 500mA by default, so if your motor draws more than that, you'll have problems. Do you know what the current draw is at 5V ?